# how to fit the video inside of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, iframe

I am using an `iframe` tag to play a video, I extended the `iframe` full `width` and `height` of the parent `div`, like this :

[image: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/0014/1091/951363/160311/20ac409fd1.jpg]

But as you can see the video won't perfectly fit in the `iframe`.

Is there any way to extend the video (like `object-fit` does for images) or adapt the `iframe` to the size of the video ?

Using CSS or JavaScript (preference using CSS).

Answer (score 1):

you need 2 separate pages: try this:

```
page 1
  <iframe width="450" height="260" src='page2.html'>
   </iframe>
page 2
 <video width="420" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
```

that way you can fit them together, and make sure width and height of iframe are about 30px more than video itself